# Playback of recorded kinect depth stream on matlab - cdata not in uint8 type

Tags: matlab, kinect, record, playback, uint8t

I am new to Matlab and Kinect programming. I have managed to struggle through to line 155 of 162 of my code but now I have come stuck and would appreciate any help.

I am trying to record both colour and depth streams so that I can image process them later without have to stream live every time I want to test it. I have managed the colour stream but the depth stream seems more difficult.

I am getting "Error using hgMovie. Movie cdata must be of type uint8 array"

I have tried using line depthMov=uint8(depthMov); as suggested by one forum but now I get "Conversion to uint8 from struct is not possible" any other suggestions? Below are snippets of the code I am trying to use.

```
    depthVid=videoinput('kinect',2,'Depth_640x480');
    set(depthVid, 'LoggingMode', 'Disk&Memory');
    depthLogfile = VideoWriter('depthlogfile.mj2'), 'Motion JPEG 200');
    depthVid.DiskLogger = depthLogfile;

    triggerconfig(depthVid, 'manual');
    set(depthVid, 'FramesPerTrigger',inf);

    start(depthVid);
    pause(20);
    trigger(depthVid);
    [depthFrameData, depthTimeData, depthMetaData] = getdata(depthVid);
    stop(depthVid)

    depthPlayback=Video('depthlogfile.mj2');

    dFrames=depthPlayback.NumberOfFrames;
    dheight=depthPlayback.Height;
    dWidth=depthPlayback.Width;

    depthMov(1:dFrames)=struct('cdata,zeros(dHeight,dWidth,3,'unit8'),'colormap',[]);

    for k = 1:dFrames
         depthMov(k).cdata=read(depthPlayback,k);
    end

    hf2 = figure;
    set (hf2,'position',[150 150 dWidth dHeight])

    %depthMov = uint(depthMov); % failed conversion

    movie(hf2,depthMov,1,depthPlayback.FrameRate); %Line I am getting the error
```

Thank you for any help or advice in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable `depthMov` is a [structural array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html), the video data for each frame is the field `cdata`.

for your application it look like you need to make sure the data in `depthMov.cdata` is uint8.

in your code you can do this as you assign each frame to `depthMov.cdata` in the for loop.

try this

```
 for k = 1:dFrames
     depthMov(k).cdata=uint8(read(depthPlayback,k));
 end
```

NB the line above this in your code has, what i presume, is a typo and should be

```
depthMov(1:dFrames)=struct('cdata',zeros(dHeight,dWidth,3,'unit8'),'colormap',[]);
```

see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-types_data-types.html) for more on matlab fundamentals including different data types.

Comment: That was brilliant and solved the issue but now I get that the 'Indexed movie frame must have a non-empty colourmap'

I have tried looking up the struct which has the form 
        s = struct(field1,value1,...,fieldN,valueN)
so i tried changing it to
        depthMov(1:dFrames)=struct('cdata',zeros(dHeight,dWidth,3,'unit8'),'colormap','gray');
so I now get the error saying 'Movie colourmap must be double arrays'

any advice with this as I want it to play the movie back in gray scale.

Comment: there is a difference between the string `'gray'` and what is returned by the function call `gray`. See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/introducing-matlab-fundamental-classes-data-types-68991.html) about basic data types in matlab for more info  for more info

Comment: This playback is being returned both upside down and only in black and white. I have 3 ideas as to why this may be the case:

1) The converting to 8-bit process
2) The Motion JPEG 2000 format or
3) The colormap - which I now have as gray(256)

Do you have any ideas on this?